# is there a way to get only a Ruby class' class methods

Tags: ruby

I use:

```
1.9.3-p448 :057 > Object.methods
 => 270 
1.9.3-p448 :058 > Object.instance_methods
 => 153
```

but is there a way to just get class methods like:

```
1.9.3-p448 :058 > Object.class_methods
```

I know I could:

```
1.9.3-p448 :057 > Object.methods - Object.instance_methods
```

but is there a way to just get them directly? Also, is there anything it could be besides a class method in the latter?

thx

Comment: Maybe `Object.class.instance_methods` - not the same as your `Object.methods - Object.instance_methods`, but perhaps the wanted result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`klass.methods` gives the class methods for class `klass`.

```
Dir.methods
# => [:open, :foreach, :entries, :chdir, :getwd, :pwd, :chroot, :mkdir, :rmdir,
:delete, :unlink, :home, :glob, :[], :exist?, :exists?, :allocate, :new,
:superclass, :freeze, :===, :==, :<=>, :<, :<=, :>, :>=, :to_s, :inspect,
:included_modules, :include?, :name, :ancestors, :instance_methods,
:public_instance_methods, :protected_instance_methods, :private_instance_methods,
:constants, :const_get, :const_set, :const_defined?, :const_missing,
:class_variables, :remove_class_variable, :class_variable_get,
:class_variable_set, :class_variable_defined?, :public_constant,
:private_constant, :module_exec, :class_exec, :module_eval, :class_eval,
:method_defined?, :public_method_defined?, :private_method_defined?,
:protected_method_defined?, :public_class_method, :private_class_method,
:autoload, :autoload?, :instance_method, :public_instance_method, :nil?, :=~,
:!~, :eql?, :hash, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :taint, :tainted?,
:untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :frozen?, :methods, :singleton_methods,
:protected_methods, :private_methods, :public_methods, :instance_variables,
:instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set, :instance_variable_defined?,
:remove_instance_variable, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send,
:public_send, :respond_to?, :extend, :display, :method, :public_method,
:define_singleton_method, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for, :equal?, :!, :!=,
:instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__send__, :__id__]
```

`klass.methods(false)` gives the class methods for `klass` that are directly defined on `klass`.

```
Dir.methods(false)
# => [:open, :foreach, :entries, :chdir, :getwd, :pwd, :chroot, :mkdir, :rmdir,
:delete, :unlink, :home, :glob, :[], :exist?, :exists?]
```

Comment: diligent explanation :-)

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I do think that OP is looking for class methods,not instances methods at all. `methods` will give you all.

Answer (score 2):

`Object.singleton_class.instance_methods`

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, that will give you instance methods of whatever the object's class is. If you want class methods of the given object, you'd access its singleton class.

Comment: But we're talking about capital 'O' Object (i.e., default root of all Ruby objects), and Object.singleton_class.instance_methods == Object.class.instance_methods => true.  Note Object.class => Class and Object.singleton_class.ancestors.first => Class.

Comment: After looking at the other answers, I see the poster was using 'Object' to refer to a generic object.  Something like 'MyObject' would have been been clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
YourObject.class.methods
```